# How to configure the ripple color for a React Native Pressable?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, pressable

The docs mention that the property `android_ripple` takes an argument of type `RippleConfig`, but when you click the link for `RippleConfig` you get a 404.

**Doc page:** https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable/#android_ripple-android

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all redirects are broken but below
https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable/#rippleconfig

Comment: Oh jeez, it's at the bottom of the same page, that's an embarrassing oversight on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your Pressable button pass in a "mode" prop into the Android_ripple config object, for example:

```
const LogininWithIcon = ({ iconName, onPress, buttonTitle, mode }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
 <Pressable
        activeOpacity={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0.58 : null}
        android_ripple={{
          color:
            mode === "facebook" ? Colors.facebookColor : Colors.googleYellow,
          borderless: false,
        }}
...
```

Then in the component that will be using the button, pass in the prop like this:

```
 <LogininWithIcon
            iconName="logo-facebook"
            onPress={() => {}}
            buttonTitle="Facebook"
            color="blue"
            mode="facebook"
          />
etc...
```